# How do I get a mapping of Pid to Port?

Tags: networking, process, lsof

I have a process which I need to run on a specific port.  I have started some other process on that port and I need to kill it.

Unfortunately, I don't remember the name/pid of the other process so I need a quick way to find which PID are associated with it.

I tried `lsof -i :7080` but that returned nothing.  I can `telnet localhost 7080` so I know its running.

For reference I'm running RHEL5

Answer (score 12):

Try:

```
netstat -nap | grep 7080
```

Comment: It might be better to use `netstat -nap | grep :7080`. Especially for lower ports it reduces the output a lot.

Comment: why does this produce an answer when lsof -i:7080 doesn't? OR does it?

Answer (score 3):

In FreeBSD:

```
sockstat -4
```

for IPV6

```
sockstat -6
```

Answer (score 0):

As root, with `ss` installed:

```
ss -p -l '( sport = :7080 )'
```

You should also check the files in `/etc/xinetd.d` and the output of `rpcinfo -p`